# Bash: echo string that starts with "-"

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

```
VAR="-e xyz"
echo $VAR
```

This prints `xyz`, for some reason. I don't seem to be able to find a way to get a string to start with `-e`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `VAR` contains `-e xyz`, if you access the variable via `$` the `-e` is interpreted as a command-line option for `echo`. Note that the content of `$VAR` is not wrapped into `""` automatically.

Use `echo "$VAR"` to fix your problem.

Comment: the doublequotes don't fixe the problem, when VAR is "-e" only

Comment: This is incorrect and should not be marked as the correct answer. See the answer by @camh

Answer (score 61):

The answers that say to put `$VAR` in quotes are only correct by side effect. That is, when put in quotes, `echo(1)` receives a single argument of `-e xyz`, and since that is not a valid option string, `echo` just prints it out. It is a side effect as `echo` could just as easily print an error regarding malformed options. Most programs will do this, but it seems GNU `echo` (from `coreutils`) and the version built into `bash` simply echo strings that start with a hyphen but are not valid argument strings. This behaviour is not documented so it should not be relied upon.

Further, if `$VAR` contains a valid `echo` option argument, then quoting $VAR will not help:

```
$ VAR="-e"
$ echo "$VAR"

$
```

Most GNU programs take `--` as an argument to mean no more option processing — all the arguments after `--` are to be processed as non-option arguments. `bash echo` does not support this so you cannot use it. Even if it did, it would not be portable. `echo` has other portability issues (`-n` vs `\c`, no `-e`).

The correct and portable solution is to use `printf(1)`.

```
printf "%s\n" "$VAR"
```

Comment: Mostly correct answer. Although POSIX standard clearly says "Implementations shall not support any options", historically part of implementations do support options (violating the standard). So `printf` is the right solution, `echo` should really be used to output some constant strings like "Hello world" which you know do not contain dashes or backslashes.

Comment: Great answer.  Been trying to figure this out for a bit now.  thank you.

Comment: If you are hell-bent on using `echo`, you can use escape sequences `echo -e '\055e'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "$VAR"
```

instead.

(`-e` is a valid option for `echo` - this is what causes this phenomenon).

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, you can use a single dash (`-`) before your arguments. This ensures that no following arguments are interpreted as options.

```
% VAR="-e xyz"
% echo - $VAR
-e xyz
```

From the `zsh` docs:

```
   echo [ -neE ] [ arg ... ]
          ...
          Note that for standards compliance a double dash does not
          terminate option processing; instead, it is printed directly.
          However, a single dash does terminate option processing, so the
          first dash, possibly following options, is not printed, but
          everything following it is printed as an argument.

         The single dash behaviour is different from other shells.
```

Keep in mind this behavior is specific to `zsh`.

Comment: This is an interesting hint, but it doesn't explain "What is going on here" ;)